# Escaping missing parenthesis using pandas str.match

Tags: python, pandas, match

I'm having trouble with regex. I'm trying to check if my database fully matches with the item name I'm working. The problem is that sometimes the data is incomplete and I'll get errors. I would like to ignore regex completely as it is not necessary at this point.

For example the code below returns `re.error: missing ), unterminated subpattern at position 10` as the last item on the list is missing a parenthesis. I've tried using `if database['Item Name'].str.match(item, regex=False).any():` but it's not enough as the items can be named quite similarly and I would need perfect match. I've also tried to read re module documentation but I do not understand it well enough to get rid of the problem.

Any ideas how could I bypass the issue?

```
database = pd.read_csv("database.csv", sep=";")

list = ["Test Name !", "Test Name (2020)", "Test name ("]

for item in list:
    if database['Item Name'].str.match(item).any():
        # do something
        pass
    else:
        #do something else
        pass
```

Comment: Did you tried to escape brackets like list = ["Test Name !", "Test Name \\(2020\\)", "Test name \\("] ?

Comment: @AlexandraDudkina, I did try manually adding them and it worked but don't know what would be the most convenient method to manipulate the string in place. If the string does not exist in database I'm appending it there. I would like to avoid to have such ugly data.

One way could be using `item.replace(')', '\))` and replace it again after if statement. I'm certain there's a more clean way to do that. As a beginner I do not know better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your post correctly, you are trying to use the data read to create a regex. Since you don't want these treated as regexes, you might simply use string comparisons.

However, if your application requires the use of regex, you can use re.escape() render the string as literal so the paren won’t be magic.

For example:

```
import re
string1 = 'this is a magic ( that will break your regex'
string2 = re.escape(string1)  # escapes your string

re.match(string2, "this won't cause issues")
#re.match(string1, "this will cause issues")
```

Comment: Thanks, never thought this would be that easy to solve. Works perfectly with the following if statement.

`if database['Item Name'].str.match(re.escape(item)).any():`